# Removing leading zeros from custom permalink structure

Tags: permalinks

My WordPress website currently uses this custom permalink structure:
%author%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%

In this case, %monthnum% instantiates numbered dates with a leading zero -- e.g., "09" for September. So, a sample URL might look like this:
mywebsite.com/username/2012/09/12/post-name

Is there a function I can add or .htaccess change that I can make which will remove the leading zeros from my permalink stucture? So, using the example above, my URLs would ideally look like this:
mywebsite.com/username/2012/9/12/post-name

Thank you! I've read up on WordPress' structure tags documentation (http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks), but I can't find any solutions or plugins for the above-mentioned problem.

Comment: Added code to htaccess, still it didn't work, moreover it broke all my images.

Answer (score 7):

**How about using custom rewrite tags/structure?**

So we'll be using these two [*rewrite/structure tags*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags):

1. `%monthnum2%` does the same thing as the `%monthnum%` tag, but without a leading zero; e.g. `3` and not `03` for March.
2. `%day2%` does the same thing as the `%day%` tag, but without a leading zero; e.g. `7` and not `07`.

**The steps:**

1. In the theme functions file (`functions.php`), add:

   ```
   add_action( 'init', function(){
       add_rewrite_tag( '%monthnum2%', '([0-9]{1,2})', 'monthnum=' );
       add_rewrite_tag( '%day2%',      '([0-9]{1,2})', 'day=' );
   } );
   ```

   That will generate the `%monthnum2%` and `%day2%` (rewrite) tags and be used when WordPress (re-)generates the rewrite rules.

   And then add this:

   ```
   add_filter( 'post_link', function( $permalink, $post ){
       if ( preg_match( '/%(?:monthnum2|day2)%/', $permalink ) ) {
           $time = strtotime( $post->post_date );
           $date = explode( ' ', date( 'n j', $time ) );

           $permalink = str_replace( [
               '%monthnum2%',
               '%day2%',
           ], [
               $date[0],
               $date[1],
           ], $permalink );

           $permalink = user_trailingslashit( $permalink, 'single' );
       }
       return $permalink;
   }, 10, 2 );
   ```

   That will replace the rewrite tags in the permalink.
2. Go to the permalink settings page and then in the "*Custom Structure*" box, enter this structure: `/%year%/%monthnum2%/%day2%/%postname%/` or `/%author%/%year%/%monthnum2%/%day2%/%postname%`, whichever applies.

   The point is, use `%monthnum2%` to display the month number *without a leading zero* and `%day2%` to display the day number *without a leading zero*.
3. Save your changes — both the theme functions file and the permalink settings — and go to the "Posts" page (`wp-admin/edit.php`) and just check everything (mouse-over the post permalink and visit the post).

Comment: I just tried this on plain wp install and it doesn't work. I have tested the $permalink value being returned, and that's good. It's just that wordpress still puts 0s in. Perhaps it's .htaccess, not sure

Comment: @Milos, I tested the code on a default WordPress 5.5.3 install, and the code worked fine for me. So, are you aware that the answer is for the default `post` post type only? Have you followed all of the steps like using `%monthnum2%` in place of `%monthnum%` - note the `2`.

Comment: yes, as I said, tested on plain install, no plugins whatsoever. Used the code in twentytwenty theme, used monthnum2 and day2, and it still shows original urls. Also, I have tested your code, just before permalink is returned, the proper permalink is returned, that's for sure.

Comment: Ok, to add to this. Not sure why, but on this server, apparently, setting callbacks as anonymous functions doesn't work. So yeah, it's all good now.

Comment: Wish I knew how to make them show up as clickable button in the ***"Available tags:"*** list in the `Permalink Settings`... thanks though this works as needed just the same

Comment: @CrandellWS not sure if you're still looking.. but you can do that using a filter hook named [`available_permalink_structure_tags`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/available_permalink_structure_tags/). See example [here](https://gist.github.com/5ally/47177bd66ce84ef6ab6a5f8411c78d84). PS: Sorry for the late reply..

Answer (score 4):

Filter `'month_link'` and `'day_link'`, WordPress will find the matching posts then without further work.

Sample code:

```
add_filter( 'month_link', 't5_strip_leading_zeros_in_url' );
add_filter( 'day_link',   't5_strip_leading_zeros_in_url' );

function t5_strip_leading_zeros_in_url( $url )
{
    // no pretty permalinks
    if ( ! $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->get_month_permastruct() )
    {
        return $url;
    }

    return str_replace( '/0', '/', $url );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not obvious to me: What file should this code be placed in? Thank you!

Comment: @DinaDadian This should go into a new plugin.

Comment: @toscho Thank you! I tried using this code in a new plugin (my plugin activated just fine), but I'm not seeing a change in my permalinks structure. Also tried adding the code to my functions.php file, but this didn't work either. Sorry! Any ideas? In case this matters, one more detail -- my website is built on top of BuddyPress 1.6.

Comment: Ah, someone helped me pinpoint the issue here. The solution above applies to month and day links. In order to have it apply to the entire post link, add this to the beginning of @toscho's code: `add_filter( 'the_permalink',   't5_strip_leading_zeros_in_url' );` Works great for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tick the check mark (✔) below the vote buttons if my answer solved your problem. :)

Comment: I had to move `add_filter` to after the function, but otherwise this is elegant and non-intrusive (except when your post slug leads with a `0`, e.g. `.../2018/12/27/0-day-exploit...`).

Answer (score 0):

htaccess solution

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*?/.*?/[0][1-9]/.*?/.*?$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/[0]([1-9])/ /$1/$2/$3/ [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I created a working example for you to test [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=02c14795-0543-544a-bd55-ca0a06830a15)

What this does is check for the path structure provided if the third path contains, a leading 0 and number 1-9, eg /03/, then applies the rewrite rule to the *third-path*, leaving the first two paths and additional paths intact `(.*?)/(.*?)/`. The rule only changes the third path if that path matches (01-09) `[0]([1-9])` from eg /03/ to /3/.

Does not affect /uploads/ month images path because the uploads structure does not match the structure provided. Please test using above link to see if it suits your needs.